# Can I get computed tensors to connect to the placeholders they fill in my TensorBoard graph?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, graph-visualization, tensorboard

I'm confused about how to get my TensorBoard graph visualization to capture the fact that I'm feeding computed values to some of my placeholders.

I have defined placeholders

```
with tf.name_scope('params'):
    keep_prob_later = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob_later')
    keep_prob_early = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob_early')
    keep_prob_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob_input')
```

and corresponding tensors for computing their values

```
with tf.name_scope('param_vals'):    
    with tf.name_scope('keep_prob_later_val'):
        keep_prob_later_val = tf.sub(1.0, tf.train.exponential_decay(1 - FLAGS.keep_prob_later, global_step,
                                                                     FLAGS.decay_steps,
                                                                     FLAGS.dropout_decay_rate, staircase=False))
    with tf.name_scope('keep_prob_early_val'):
        keep_prob_early_val = tf.sub(1.0, tf.train.exponential_decay(1 - FLAGS.keep_prob_early, global_step,
                                                                     FLAGS.decay_steps,
                                                                     FLAGS.dropout_decay_rate, staircase=False))
    with tf.name_scope('keep_prob_input_val'):
        keep_prob_input_val = tf.sub(1.0, tf.train.exponential_decay(1 - FLAGS.keep_prob_input, global_step,
                                                                     FLAGS.decay_steps,
                                                                     FLAGS.dropout_decay_rate, staircase=False))
```

which I then feed when I train my model

```
sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys,
                                keep_prob_later: sess.run(keep_prob_later_val),
                                keep_prob_early: sess.run(keep_prob_early_val),
                                keep_prob_input: sess.run(keep_prob_input_val)})
```

but my TensorBoard graph visualization does not show these "hooked up".

I see the placeholders connected correctly to the rest of my graph

[image]

and I see all of the corresponding computed values too

[image]

but the latter don't connect to the former.

Is this the expected be behavior? Is there a way to capture in the TensorBoard visualization of my graph the fact that the computed values are used to fill the corresponding placeholders?

---

If there's no way to connect the computed values to the graph, why show them? And why other computed values appear correctly. For example, my computed momentum values, which are defined just like the above fed dropout values

```
with tf.name_scope('param_vals'):
    with tf.name_scope('momentum_val'):
        momentum_val = tf.sub(1.0, tf.train.exponential_decay(1 - FLAGS.initial_momentum, global_step,
                                                          FLAGS.decay_steps, FLAGS.momentum_decay_rate,
                                                          staircase=False))
```

do show up connected to all the parts of the graph they influence.

Comment: Why do you use an intermediate `tf.placeholder` for the `keep_prob_***`, instead of just using the Tensors `keep_prob_***_val` you computed?

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot: I need to feed the placeholders. Sometimes I feed the corresponding `... _val` (for training) and sometimes I feed `1.0` (for prediction and for validation).

Comment: Anyway it is the normal behavior that TensorFlow does not see the connection, because the connection is done in Python, without TensorFlow knowing it. If you want to see the connection you could use a `tf.cond()` thing, with a boolean `train as the condition?

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot: That makes sense and would work as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see the placeholders connected correctly to the rest of my graph, and I see all of the corresponding computed values too, but the latter don't connect to the former.
>
> Is this the expected be behavior?

Indeed it is the correct behavior. Your graph is decomposed in two parts:

1. The part where you compute the values `keep_prob_***_val`
2. The part where you define the placeholders `keep_prob_***`

Parts 1 and 2 are not connected in the graph. When you call `sess.run(keep_prob_***_val)`, you create a Python object. This object is then fed to the second part of the graph, but the graph doesn't know it comes from the first part.

---

> Is there a way to capture in the TensorBoard visualization of my graph the fact that the computed values are used to fill the corresponding placeholders?

You can use `tf.cond()` ([doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#cond)) to choose between using the values computed in the first part of the graph, or the test values (like `1.` for `keep_prob`):

```py
is_train = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, [])

def when_train():
    return keep_prob_late_val

def when_not_train():
    return 1.

keep_prob_later = tf.cond(is_train, when_train, when_not_train)
```

---

> And why other computed values appear correctly. For example, my computed momentum values, which are defined just like the above fed dropout values do show up connected to all the parts of the graph they influence.

In this case, you do not use an **intermediate placeholder** so the graph is fully connected !